# Unable to navigate to another page on button click in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a button & upon clicking it, I need to go to another xaml page.

This button resides in Page1.xaml

```
<Button Content="Button Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" Foreground="#FF119FF0"/>


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       frameBody.Navigate(typeof(HomePage)); 
    }
```

But I am not able to navigate to HomePage.xaml.

What can be the reason??

These are the libraries I included:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
```

The function Button_Click() is defined in Page1.xaml.cs.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program?

Comment: Does your function get called? What happens when you step into the Navigate function? See anything strange?

Comment: frameBody does not exist in current context. @Benjamin Diele

Comment: @WD You might want to create that variable then, or just use `Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that I use in my project:

```
    private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var albumId = ((Album)e.ClickedItem).Id;
        if (!Frame.Navigate(typeof(AlbumPage), albumId))
        {
            var resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Resources");
            throw new Exception(resourceLoader.GetString("NavigationFailedExceptionMessage"));
        }
    }
```

The part to focus on is `Frame.Navigate(typeof(AlbumPage))`.

I want to pass some information to that page, that's why I pass my `albumId`.

If you want to retrieve the passed argument in your other page, you might want to use this code:

```
    private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        var albumId = (int)e.NavigationParameter;
    }
```

Comment: OK. Got it. Since I don't want to pass any information my code should be like  Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage)); Right??? @Benjamin Diele

Comment: @WD Indeed. Just that `Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage))`

Comment: Can you tell me how you get the value albumId in your next page?? @Benjamin Diele

Answer (score 2):

I think You are missing a directive or an assembly reference?

for window phone 8.1 navigation

```
 Frame.Navigate(typeof(Urpage));
```

for  window phone 8.0

```
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/URpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are using a windows phone sliverlight project and your class is extending/inheriting "PhoneApplicationPage" like this :

```
public partial class Example : PhoneApplicationPage
{
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {    
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Homepage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));   
        }  
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is for Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

Another most important point to notice is you might want to check 'App.xaml.cs' file and within OnLaunched method change the

```
   rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(UrPage),e.Arguments);
```

by default MainPage.xaml loads.